# Open folder which contains comma in its path

Tags: c#, .net

I need to open folder through windows explorer using C#. 
It is working fine untill there is comma in folder path. Here is an example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", "C:\\folder\\another-folder\\123,456");
```

The error is: The path '456' does not exist or it is not a directory.

Any solution please :)

Comment: did you try escaping it?

Comment: @st0le: There is nothing to be escaped; it just needs to be surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 16):

Try adding double quotes around your path:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", "\"C:\\folder\\another-folder\\123,456\"");
```

Side-note: you might find it easier to write paths using a verbatim string literal, to avoid having to escape the slashes:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"""C:\folder\another-folder\123,456""");
```

Comment: You would also need to do this if the path contained other special characters, such as space. So, to be safe, path strings should always be double quoted.

Answer (score 2):

Try to surround the path with double-quotes:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", "\"C:\\folder\\another-folder\\123,456\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the file name:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", "\"C:\\folder\\another-folder\\123,456\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the @ operator before the path string ...and then simply write down the path without any escape characters like backslashes etc. It makes the string verbatim.

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\myapp.exe"); // should work