# How to use Call Shell when there are commas in a folder directory?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use Call Shell to open up windows explorer to a pre-determined directory saved as string.

e.g. `FolderDirectory = P:/Address, Postcode`

Then

```
Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " * FolderDirectory, vbNormalFocus)
```

It works when there is no comma in the directory but when there is a comma it just opens up the documents directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using chr(130)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a folder named `Address, Postcode` in my Temp Folder and this code worked for me:

```
Dim FolderDirectory As String
FolderDirectory = "C:\Temp\Address, Postcode"
Call Shell("explorer.exe " & """" & FolderDirectory & """", vbNormalFocus)
```

Hope you can adapt it to your needs

It looks like when there is a comma on it, you need to double quote the path. For this answer, I based on what I read here:

[Open folder which contains comma in its path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749569/open-folder-which-contains-comma-in-its-path)

Comment: @DouglasWicker it works because when a path includes spaces or special (but legal) characters, it needs to be enclosed in double quotes. To include double quotes in a string literal (itself delimited with double quotes), you must *double* the double quotes, so `foo = """"` makes `foo` contain the string value `"`.